# Objective C: Accessing next cell of a UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

How can I access (to change the imageView.image) the next cell of my UITableView given that I already have:

`UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
NSIndexPath *newPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row+1 inSection:indexPath.section];
UITableViewCell *nextCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: newPath];
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be cellForRowAtIndexPath:newPath?

Comment: What if the next cell is in a different section